# excel - count if multiple words are in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have values

```
 AA,BB,CC
 AA,CC
 AA
 AA,BB
 BB
 BB,CC
 CC
 CC,AA
 CC,BB
 BB,CC,DD
```

find all cells that have. how do I search for each values.

```
 AA,BB = 2
 BB,CC = 4
```

Example

```
COUNTIFS($A:$A,"*AA*",$A:$A,"*BB*") doesn't seem to work.
```

Comment: `=COUNTIFS($A:$A,"*AA*",$A:$A,"*BB*")` ?

Comment: @Spectral Instance, I had the Astrid but it didn't display thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was

```
COUNTIFS($A:$A,"*"&$C$2&"*",$A:$A,"*"&$C$3&"*")
```

C2 = AA
C3 = BB

Comment: It only applies for the case of two words, if you are looking for three words or just one word you need to modify the formula all the time. The question states: **multiple**. It is a very nice solution but only valid under this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this using `wildcards` **`*`** with `TEXTBEFORE()` & `TEXTAFTER()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `D2`

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A10,"*"&TEXTBEFORE(C2,",")&"*",A1:A10,"*"&TEXTAFTER(C2,",")&"*")
```

---

### EDIT

As suggested by **[Tom Sharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3894917/tom-sharpe)** Sir,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `D2`

```
=LET(x,TEXTSPLIT(C2,","),y,COUNTA(x),
SUM(--(MMULT(N(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(x,$A$1:$A$10))),SEQUENCE(y,,1,0))=y)))
```

---

Comment: Thanks for this but BB,dd,cc it's result should be 1 but it's 0.  The values should be searched across the cells individually.

Comment: How do you get `BB,dd,cc` as one because it gives me 4 with the second formula

Comment: thanks for the response. It should give you 1 since only one cell has all 3 of those values.  Perhaps it's a poor example what I'm looking for is that value in Column C should be searched in column A. if it has all those values in column c it adds the number of occurencies of that.

Comment: I agree with you but, if it gives you one, then the examples sighted for `AA,BB` & `BB,CC` should give you as 1 as well. Thats because if you are counting the cells individually, which doesnt happens for the given two.

Comment: It actually doesn't have to split the column C values. I can manually enter the values. I just want to be able to search multiple values through column A.

Comment: Can you show me what should be the count of `CC,BB,AA` ?

Comment: Maybe formula should be =LET(x,TEXTSPLIT(C2,","),
SUM(--(MMULT(N(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(x,$A$1:$A$10))),SEQUENCE(COUNTA(x),,1,0))=COUNTA(x))))
?

Comment: @TomSharpe Sir, absolutely correct. I have not edited the same, because OP, had search words in different cells, while they have posted in the query with a delimiter. If you permit, I will update the same.

Comment: Please do - up to  you whether you want to put counta(x) as a named  value in the let to avoid repetition etc.

Comment: @TomSharpe Sir, thank you, I will update the same as you have suggested.

Comment: Be carefull for false positives. To see what I mean, change `A1` into `AAA,BB,CC`.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `D2`:

```
=MAP(C2:C5,LAMBDA(z,SUM(MAP(A1:A11,LAMBDA(x,LET(y,TEXTSPLIT(z,,","),N(SUM(N(TEXTSPLIT(x,",")=y))=ROWS(y))))))))
```

**Note:** My answer assumes no duplicates in the values in column A:A. e.g.: `AA,AA`.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
=LET(searchvalues,  C2,
     data,          $A$1:$A$10,
     split,         TEXTSPLIT(searchvalues,","),
     count,         COLUMNS(split),
SUM(
    --(MMULT(
             --ISNUMBER(SEARCH(split,data)),
             SEQUENCE(count,,1,0))
       =count)))
```

It splits the values you want to search (stored in `C2` in my example) into individual values: `split`

Than `split` is searched within each row of your `data`.
This returns TRUE or FALSE wrapped in `--` changes TRUE to 1 and FALSE to 0.
This is used within MMULT and this returns the sum of the occurrences of each individual `split` value. Finally the MMULT result needs to equal the number of splitted search values.
The sum of this being true is the end result.

Answer (score 1):

The following approach considers a variable number of words to search, not just `2` words as in the input sample:

```
=LET(lk, B1, A, $A$1:$A$11, lks, TEXTSPLIT(lk,, ","),
  byr, BYROW(A, LAMBDA(x,SUM(COUNTIF(x,"*"&lks&"*")))), SUM(N(byr=ROWS(lks))))
```

It has a caveat that if the word is repeated more than one time per row in the first column, it is counted as `1`, as you can see in the following output. This is because of how `COUNTIF` (or `COUNTIFS`) works with wildcards (other answers provided using `SEARCH` produce the same result). If that assumption is ok, then it works. The rest is just to drag the formula down (*formula1*).

**UPDATE**: Considering @JvdV's comment, to avoid false positive when the word to search could be a substring of the column `A` on a given row. Like for example, searching the word `AA`, in the string: `AAA` will produce a false positive. The following version avoids it:

```
=LET(lk, B1, A, $A$1:$A$11, lks, TEXTSPLIT(lk,, ","),
 byr, BYROW(A, LAMBDA(x, SUM(N(TEXTSPLIT(x,",") = lks)))), SUM(N(byr=ROWS(lks))))
```

Here is the output:
[image: excel output1]

I added intentionally the highlighted cases to test additional situations. Row `11` repeats the word: `AA`, and `BB`, but it is counted as `1` in the final result.

The following approach tries to identify the total number of counts considering repetitions of the word in column **A** (*formula2*):

```
=LET(lk, B1, A, $A$1:$A$11, lks, TEXTSPLIT(lk,, ","),
 byr, BYROW(A, LAMBDA(x, LET(match, IFERROR(TOCOL(XMATCH(TEXTSPLIT(x, ","),
 lks),2),0), ux, UNIQUE(match), IF(ROWS(ux) < ROWS(lks), 0,
   MIN(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(N(match = TOROW(ux))), SEQUENCE(ROWS(match),,1,0))))))),
 SUM(byr))
```

Now we get the following result:
[image: excel output2]

Now we get an additional count for the case of `AA, BB`.

In *formula2*, `match` has the index position as a result of the `XMATCH` call, we use `TOCOL` to remove non-found values `#N/A`. In case no words were found, we use `IFERROR` to assign the zero value. The `IF` condition:

```
IF(ROWS(ux) < ROWS(lks)
```

Ensures to calculate non-zero counts only if all words were found. We use `MMULT` to calculate per row the number of repetitions of the lookup words. We take the minimum, to ensure we only consider the scenarios where all the words are present. There could be a situation, where one of the lookup words has more counts than another one, which is why we take the minimum. Therefore we are counting the entire set of lookup words found regardless of the order,

Comment: A 2nd caveat with `COUNTIF()` is the possibility of false positives. Say, change `A1` to 'AAA,BB,CC' to see what I mean.

Comment: Good catch @JvdV, true. Because it finds the first substring, similar to `SEARCH("Apple","Apples")` returns `1`, so the other previous answers have the same issue, or assumption.

Comment: Yes, all previous answers have the same issue in this regard. To me it seems all these options are placeholders and not actually working data. For what it's worth, your 2nd option works!

Comment: yes, indeed, I added an update to my answer giving you credit on how to solve the false positive for *formula1* which at the end is your non-array version.